# rg.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

This error does not allow me to have access to the jsondoc, I have tried some of the solutions provided here, but I still have the same problem.

I hope I have been clear enough with what I want you to help me.

I leave the error and also one of the classes mentioned in the error.

```
      Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot  
      simultaneously fetch multiple bags: 
      [com.credix.sib.canales.applicant.Applicant.phoneApplicant, 
      com.credix.sib.canales.applicant.Applicant.addressApplicant]
```

Added one of the classes that was shown in the error

```
      @Entity
   @Table(name="APL_APPLICANT", schema="CREDITAPPLICATION")
   @NamedQuery(name="Applicant.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Applicant a")
   public class Applicant implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="APL_Id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@ApiObjectField(description = "Id del Aplicante", required = true)
private Long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="APL_CreateDate", updatable=false)
@ApiObjectField(description = "Fecha de creación del Aplicante", required = true)
private Date createDate;

@Column(name="APL_Email")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Email del Aplicante", required = true)
private String email;

@Column(name="APL_Identification", updatable=false)
@ApiObjectField(description = "Identificación del Aplicante", required = true)
private String identification;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="APL_LastModifiedDate")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Fecha de la última modificación del Aplicante", required = true)
private Date lastModifiedDate;

@Column(name="APL_PrintName")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Nombre del Aplicante", required = true)
private String printName;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="APS_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Objeto Status del Aplicante", required = true)
private ApplicantStatus applicantStatus;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="IDT_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Objeto tipo de identificación del Aplicante", required = true)
private IdentificationType identificationType;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="USU_IdCreate")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Objeto usuario creador del Aplicante")
private User userCreate;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="USU_IdLastModified", updatable = false)
@ApiObjectField(description = "Objeto usuario ultima modificación del Aplicante")
private User userLastModified;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="APL_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Objeto que contiene los datos personales del aplicante")
private PersonApplicant personApplicant;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="APL_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Lista de direcciones del aplicante")
private List<AddressApplicant> addressApplicant;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="APL_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Lista de números telefónicos del aplicante")
private List<PhoneApplicant> phoneApplicant;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="APL_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Lista de tipos de notificación del aplicante")
private List<PublicityNotification> publicityNotification;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CTR_Id")
@ApiObjectField(description = "Objeto tipo de Pais", required = true)
private Country country;

public Applicant() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getCreateDate() {
    return this.createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getIdentification() {
    return this.identification;
}

public void setIdentification(String identification) {
    this.identification = identification;
}

public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
    return this.lastModifiedDate;
}

public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
}

public String getPrintName() {
    return this.printName;
}

public void setPrintName(String printName) {
    this.printName = printName;
}

public ApplicantStatus getApplicantStatus() {
    return this.applicantStatus;
}

public void setApplicantStatus(ApplicantStatus applicantStatus) {
    this.applicantStatus = applicantStatus;
}

public IdentificationType getIdentificationType() {
    return this.identificationType;
}

public void setIdentificationType(IdentificationType identificationType) {
    this.identificationType = identificationType;
}

public User getUserCreate() {
    return this.userCreate;
}

public void setUserCreate(User userCreate) {
    this.userCreate = userCreate;
}

public User getUserLastModified() {
    return this.userLastModified;
}

public void setUserLastModified(User userLastModified) {
    this.userLastModified = userLastModified;
}

public PersonApplicant getPersonApplicant() {
    return this.personApplicant;
}

public void setPersonApplicant(PersonApplicant personApplicant) {
    this.personApplicant = personApplicant;
}

public List<AddressApplicant> getAddressApplicant() {

ArrayList<AddressApplicant>();
        return this.addressApplicant;
}

public void setAddressApplicant(List<AddressApplicant> addressApplicant) {
    this.addressApplicant = addressApplicant;
}

public List<PhoneApplicant> getPhoneApplicant() {

ArrayList<PhoneApplicant>();

    return this.phoneApplicant;
}

public void setPhoneApplicant(List<PhoneApplicant> phoneApplicant) {
    this.phoneApplicant = phoneApplicant;
}

public List<PublicityNotification> getPublicityNotification() {

 ArrayList<PublicityNotification>();
  return this.publicityNotification;
}

public void setPublicityNotification(List<PublicityNotification> 
 publicityNotification) {
    this.publicityNotification = publicityNotification;
}

/**
 * @return the country
 */
public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

/**
 * @param country the country to set
 */
public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}
```

}

I hope some recommendation

Comment: `PhoneApplicant` does not cause the problem, `Applicant` does. Please provide source code of the latter.

Comment: ok, update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message state: you `cannot  simultaneously fetch multiple bags`.

To solve the problem you can:

1. Change the type of a collection you use for `phoneApplicant` and `addressApplicant` from `List` to `Set`. This solution will result in collections without order and no duplicates. If you insist on having ordered collection with possible duplcates use the second option described below.
2. Provide order column using annotation `@OrderColumn` for both lists.